# Add element to an inner array of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `2D` array `unique_cl_data` that is of shape `(18,3)`. I need a way of adding elements in a for loop to the inner array, so that shape (after completed `for` loop) becomes `(18,4)`. When I try to simply modify the element, it does not let me giving the error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (3)

That is the code that I have:

```
for cluster_name in assign_umap_df:
        cl_json = assign_umap_df[cluster_name].to_json()
        row_idx = [x for x in np.nonzero(unique_cl_data == 'umap')[0] if cluster_name in unique_cl_data[x]][0]
        unique_cl_data[row_idx] = np.concatenate((unique_cl_data[row_idx], [cl_json]))
```

`cl_json` is just a `JSON` string that I need to add as a `4th` element to a specific inner array with `row_idx`.

Comment: How about doing this with a list of lists, such as `unique_cl_data.tolist()`?  The inner lists of a list can be modified and append to.  `rows` of a 2d array cannot be changed in the same way.  You have to `concatenate` a (18,1) array to the (18,3) to get a new (18,4) array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just adding an empty column to the original `unique_cl_data`, so that instead of concatenation we would do just:

```
unique_cl_data[row_idx][3] = cl_json.replace('"', '\\"').replace('\n', '\\n')
```